# Getting all timeDuration from a day which are not in a list of timeDuration in Scala

Tags: list, scala, timestamp

I have a list of timestamp tuples of the form `List((startTime,endTime))`, which are basically denoting periods of time throughout the day.

For example:

```
(("2016-03-28 14:00:00","2016-03-28 15:00:00"),
 ("2016-03-28 17:00:00","2016-03-28 21:00:00"), 
 ("2016-03-28 01:00:00","2016-03-28 13:00:00"))
```

I want to get a list of the durations which are **not** included in this list.

So the output should be:

```
(("2016-03-28 00:00:00","2016-03-28 01:00:00"),
 ("2016-03-28 13:00:00","2016-03-28 14:00:00"),
 ("2016-03-28 15:00:00","2016-03-28 17:00:00"),
 ("2016-03-28 17:00:00","2016-03-28 24:00:00"))
```

Can anyone suggest a good and efficient way of doing that in Scala?

The naive solution that I've tried so far is as follows:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

def comparator(first: (Timestamp,Timestamp), second: (Timestamp, Timestamp)) = first._2.getTime <= second._1.getTime

val data = List((Timestamp.valueOf("2016-03-28 00:00:00"),Timestamp.valueOf("2016-03-28 10:00:00")),
  (Timestamp.valueOf("2016-03-28 12:00:00"),Timestamp.valueOf("2016-03-28 15:00:00")),
  (Timestamp.valueOf("2016-03-28 23:00:00"),Timestamp.valueOf("2016-03-28 23:59:59")),
  (Timestamp.valueOf("2016-03-28 16:00:00"),Timestamp.valueOf("2016-03-28 21:00:00"))
).sortWith(comparator)

var emptySlots = new ListBuffer[(Timestamp,Timestamp)]()
var currTime = Timestamp.valueOf("2016-03-28 00:00:00")
var index = 0
var cond = 0
while(cond == 0){

  if (currTime.compareTo(Timestamp.valueOf("2016-03-28 23:59:59")) < 0 && index >= data.size){
    emptySlots += ((currTime,Timestamp.valueOf("2016-03-28 23:59:59") ))
    cond = 1
  }
  else if(index >= data.size)
  {
    cond = 1
  }
  else if(currTime.compareTo(data(index)._1) < 0) {
    emptySlots += ((currTime, data(index)._1))
    currTime = data(index)._2
    index += 1
  }
  else if(currTime.compareTo(data(index)._1) >= 0 && currTime.compareTo(data(index)._2) < 0 ) {
    currTime = data(index)._2
    index += 1
  }
  else if(currTime.compareTo(data(index)._1) > 0 && currTime.compareTo(data(index)._2) > 0 ) {

    index += 1
  }

}

emptySlots.toList
```

Comment: Show us some of the, possibly inefficient, ways you came up with, and, perhaps, we would be be able to work together with you on improving them and making more efficient.

Comment: Hi Ben and Dima,

I've just added the solution that I wrote for the issue, kindly suggest some better approach, or is this the correct approach?

Comment: Should this be on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: posted it on code review as well now.